# Sorting out labels in subplots, created with fig.add_axes

Tags: matplotlib, plot, axis-labels

I am new to python and am currently playing around with mathplotlib. Below is my code for the plot, shown on the bottom figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))

ax1 = f.add_axes([0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.5],
                   xticklabels=[])
ax2 = f.add_axes([0.1, 0.4, 0.8, 0.1])

ax1.plot(particles[0, :, 0])
ax1.plot(particles[1, :, 0])
ax2.plot(distances[:])

# Prettifying the plot
plt.xlabel("t", fontsize=25)     
plt.tick_params(                 # modifying plot ticks
    axis='x', 
    labelsize=20)
plt.ylabel("x", fontsize=25)     
plt.tick_params(                 # modifying plot ticks
    axis='y',
    labelsize=20)

# Plot title
plt.title('Harmonic oscillator in ' + str(dim) + 'D with ' + str(num_step) + ' timesteps', fontsize=30)

# Saving the plot
#plt.savefig("results/2D_dif.png")
```

[image: Plot]

The two graphs have the dimensions and positions as I wish, but as you can see, the labels and the title are off. I wish to have the same label style, as was applied to the bottom plot, with the y-label of the upper plot reading "x", and the title "Harmonic oscillator ..." being on top of the first graph.

I thank you kindly for your help!

Comment: Use `ax1.set_title(..)`, `ax2.set_xlabel(..)` or whatever you need to apply to the respective axes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `plt` is acting on the most recently created axes instance (`ax2` in this case). This is why the fonts haven't changed for `ax1`!

So, to get what you want you need to explicitly act on both `ax1` and `ax2`. Something like the following should do the trick:

```
for ax in ax1, ax2:
    # Prettifying the plot
    ax.set_xlabel("t", fontsize=25)     
    ax.tick_params(                 # modifying plot ticks
        axis='x', 
        labelsize=20)
    ax.set_ylabel("x", fontsize=25)     
    ax.tick_params(                 # modifying plot ticks
        axis='y',
        labelsize=20)

    # Plot title
    ax.set_title('Harmonic oscillator in ' + str(dim) + 'D with ' + str(num_step) + ' timesteps', fontsize=30)
```

Comment: When you call to ```ax.plot``` you need to add labels. eg ```ax1.plot(particles[0, :, 0], label='Particle 1')```,  ```ax1.plot(particles[0, :, 0], label='Particle 2')```, and then ```ax1.legend()```.